# Background shows on iOS but not on Android Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin

The background image shows up on my iOS project but doesn't show up in Android. I am quite new to Xamarin so it may be quite a simple mistake.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Simple_Project.Views.ItemDetailPage"
         Title="{Binding Title}"
         BackgroundImage="Background-1.jpg">
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15">
           <!--content here-->
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

I was thinking that the BackgroundImage would take care of both iOS and Android. Unless that's wrong? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use dashes in the Android asset filename, underscores work fine, so rename...

```
Background-1.jpg
```

to

```
Background_1.jpg
```

...in your code and in all the projects, otherwise use `OnPlatform`

Comment: Didn't seem to fix the issue unfortunately. May I ask what OnPlatfrom may be?

Comment: You might want to clean and rebuild the solution... OnPlatform or RuntimePlatform :  https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.OnPlatform/

Comment: Didn't fix it either. Would the OnPlatform allow me to change the background of particular pages?